# How do I check isalpha() for only the first 5 characters of a string?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, isalpha

I want to validate a PAN card whose first 5 characters are alphabets, the next 4 are numbers and the last character is an alphabet again. I can't use isalnum() because I want to check this specific order too, not just verify whether it contains both numbers and letters.

Here is a snipped of my code:

```
def validate_PAN(pan):
    for i in pan:
        pan.isalpha(pan[0:4])==True:
            return 1
        pan.isdigit(pan[5:9])==True:
            return 1
        pan.isalpha(pan[9])==True:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

This obviously returns an error since it is wrong. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Just do string slicing and check

```
s[:5].isalpha()
```

`pan[0:4]` - Here you check for the first 4 characters and not 5 characters.

> `s[m:n]` - This will slice the string from `m`th character till `n`th character (not including `n`)

###### Mistake in your code

> `pan.isalpha(pan[0:4])==True`

This is giving you the error because `isalpha()` doesn't accept any arguments and you aren't using `if` before it.

You must use - `if pan[:5].isalpha() == True:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` for simplicity sake

```py
import re

PAN_1 = 'ABCDE1111E'
PAN_2 = 'ABC1111DEF'

def is_valid_PAN(PAN_number):
    return bool(re.match(r'[a-z]{5}\d{4}[a-z]', PAN_number, re.IGNORECASE))

print(is_valid_PAN(PAN_1)) #True
print(is_valid_PAN(PAN_2)) #False
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a good fit for this.

```
import re

# Pattern for matching a PAN number
pattern = r'\b[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]\b'

# compile the pattern for better performance with repetitive matches
pobject = re.compile(pattern)

pan_number = "AXXMP1234Z"
result = pobject.match(pan_number)

if result:
    print ("Matched for PAN: ", res.group(0))
else:
    print("Failed")
```